# Python merge sort repeating numbers

Tags: python, sorting, merge

I'm trying to learn how to do a merge sort. When I run this code though, the output is wrong. For reference I am learning from tutorialspoint.

The code is

```
import random

Listy = []

for x in range(0, 15):

    Listy.append(random.randint(1, 15))

Second = []

for x in range(0, 20):

    Second.append(None)

    #I needed to initialize an empty array

def merge(low, mid, high):

    l1 = low
    l2 = mid + 1
    i = low
    while l1 <= mid and l2 <= high:
        print("First ", l1)
        print("Second", l2)
        print(i, " is i")
        if Listy[l1] < Listy [l2]:
            print("True")
            Second[i] = Listy[l1]
            l1 = l1 + 1

        else:
            print("False")
            Second[i] = Listy[l1]
            l2 = l2 + 1
        i = i + 1


        
    while l1 <= mid:
        Second[i] = Listy[l1]
        i = i+1
        l1 = l1 + 1
    while l2 <= high:
        Second[i] = Listy[l2]
        i = i+1
        l2 = l2 + 1
    for x in range(low, high):
        Listy[x] = Second[low]
        low = low + 1
    print(Listy)
def sort(low, high):
    print("Recursion: ", low, " - ", high)
    if low < high:
        mid = int((low+high) / 2)
        sort(low, mid)
        sort(mid + 1, high)
        merge(int(low), int(mid), int(high))
    else:
        return
for x in Listy:

    print(x)

sort(0, 15)

print(Listy)
```

I do not know why but the output repeats numbers over and over. Here is the array printed by one test of the code [11, 11, 7, 13, 13, 13, 13, 11, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 2, 11]. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I assume you are asking why your code obviously is not sorting the array and not why there are duplicate numbers in your "sorted" array.

(If your question is actually is why there are duplicate numbers in your "sorted" array: because random does not check whether it already created a number (you would have to implement checking for duplicates yourself) and because your merge functions' conditions are `if ... < ...: ... else:` which is equal to `if ... < ... elif ... >= ...:...`)

Otherwise, I changed your code at some places to make it work, your main error was that `range(lowerBound, upperBound)` returns an array with the the first element being lowerBound and the last being **upperBound - 1**. Check my comments for details:

in merge(...):

```py
if Listy[l1] < Listy [l2]:
            Second[i] = Listy[l1]
            l1 = l1 + 1

        else:
            #Second[i] = Listy[l1] --> your line, you had l1 again instead of l2
            Second[i] = Listy[l2]
            l2 = l2 + 1
        i = i + 1
```

and:

```py
# for x in range(low, high): --> your line, range() creates a list where
# the upper bound is not! included
# so your range was one too short
# This caused the wierd repeated numbers (it always forgot to merge the last element)
for x in range(low, high+1):
    Listy[x] = Second[low]
    low = low + 1
```

and in order to start sorting:

```
# sort(0, 15) --> your line, 1 too long. again, range() returns a list
# where the upper bound is not included and you need to set high to
# the highest included index (14), not the length of Listy
sort(0, 14)
```